# make a copy of dead thread

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have a class that subclasses threading.thread. In the daemon that initialises the thread objects i periodically check the thread status. If the status is incomplete and the thread is not alive this means that there has been an error in doing something like an api call to another server.

My question is if this happens is it possible to make a copy of the thread object and call the start method. I had considered calling the run method again on the original object but this would mess up the daemon workflow.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an infinite loop in the daemon and check the isAlive()/is_alive() method if something has gone wrong. If it has just start up a new object using the same values.

Another way to solve your problem would be to catch the real problem within the thread object and just take care of the problem there. I assume you have a loop in your run() method. Just put everything within the loop in a try/except clause that will re-initialize whatever you are doing to check the other servers.

Something like this:

```
def run(self):
    while 1:
        try:
            if not server.isconnected():
                server.connect()

            server.getsomeinfo()
        except server.error as x:
            server.disconnect()

        time.sleep(1)
```

This will reconnect as soon as it is an error of type server.error. You can make the solution a lot prettier and add some intervals before retrying etc. I have done exactly this and it works perfectly.